# Ruby including Errors module in another module - uninitialized constant Errors

Tags: ruby

I've got NON-RAILS app where I want to include `Errors` module to `Formatter` module to access the method `error_class` from `Errors`. Like below:

```
#lib/formatter.rb
    module Formatter
      module_function
    
      include ::Errors
    
      def format(number)
        number.delete!(' ')
    
        raise error_class(:invalid_number), 'Invalid phone number, check your entries' unless valid?(number)
      end
    end

#lib/errors.rb

module Errors
  class FormatterExceptionError < StandardError; end

  PhoneNumberInvalid = Class.new(FormatterExceptionError)

  def error_class(status)
    case status
    when :invalid_number
      PhoneNumberInvalid
    end
  end
end
```

With this code I'm getting an error:

> Failure/Error: include ::Errors
> NameError:
> uninitialized constant Errors
> Did you mean?  Errno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-rails apps doesn't have auto-load classes, so you need to manually require it.
Also one thing of your code, I don't know why you are using `::` before constant, I don't see any naming-confusion in order to use it. It is used only when you have your `Errors` modules on different namespace, and you need to resolve the one from your namespace.

```
# lib_formatter
require 'errors'

module Formatter
  extend Errors
  # ...
end
```

The second issue with your code, that you have defined instance method, but where you include your code there class method (module method)

So errors class should be adjusted to

```rb
module Errors
  # ...
  module_function
  # ...
end
```

The third issue is include/extend misusage.

Include used to make all methods from module you using to become **instance** methods.
Extend used to make all methods from module you using to become **class** methods.

[include/extend info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/include-v-s-extend-in-ruby/)

Comment: Ok, I'm testing this inside the spec and I've got an error: `got #<NoMethodError: undefined method error_class' for Formatter:Module`

Comment: sure, cause in Errors, you defined instance method, but it needed to be also module_function, will update my answer.